# Not able to build libhexagon_controller.so [missing files in nnlib: GRAPHINIT := /prj/dsp/qdsp6/arch/cnn/setup/inceptionv3_uint8in.c]

Tags: tensorflow, hexagon-dsp

I have been following the steps provided at below link, for using tensorflow on hexagon.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/hvx

I facing 2 issues with the build,

```
(1) while building graph_app standalone app for checking inception v3, error reported missing file
GRAPHINIT := /prj/dsp/qdsp6/arch/cnn/setup/inceptionv3_uint8in.c in nnlib/Makefile
source: https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/hexagon_nn/nnlib
```

(2) while building libhexagon_controller.so, there is this error repoted:

```
    ------------------------------------------
     --- V = android_Debug_aarch64
     --- GLUE_DIR = glue
     --- HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT = /home/zaheer.s/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.1
     ------------------------------------------

 making /home/zaheer.s/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.1/test/common/test_util
 making /home/zaheer.s/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.1/tools/qaic
 making /home/zaheer.s/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.1/libs/common/atomic
 making /home/zaheer.s/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.1/libs/common/rpcmem
 making .
 android_Debug_aarch64/hexagon_controller.o: In function                                         `hexagon_controller_InitInputNodeDataToInceptionDummyData':
 /home/zaheer.s/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.1/examples/common/generated_hexagon_controller/src_impl/  hexagon_controller.c:74: undefined reference to `inception_dummy_int_data_224x224'
 /home/zaheer.s/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.1/examples/common/generated_hexagon_controller/src_impl/  hexagon_controller.c:74: undefined reference to `inception_dummy_int_data_224x224'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[1]: *** [android_Debug_aarch64/libhexagon_controller.so] Error 1
 ERROR making .
```

does anyone has ran tf on hexagon, please suggest your views on fixing the build issue.

**EDIT:**
graph_app needs to be evaluated standalone against inceptionv3.

Answer (score 0):

You can get past this build error by adding an integer array to `tensorflow/contrib/hvx/hexagon_controller/src_dummy_data/inception_v3_dummy_int_data.c`.

[This was suggested by `satok16` over at TF on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9428#issuecomment-299532174).

Comment: Yeah, i had raised there as an issue, i forgot to update the answer here,
thanks,

also, nnlib source comes with something like test_med.c as graph init file,
how to evaluate standalone graph_app with inception v3,
do you have any idea about GRAPHINIT := /prj/dsp/qdsp6/arch/cnn/setup/inceptionv3_uint8in.c  ?

Comment: @kzs, please ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I have asked that as first question, may be instead of graph_app I have mentioned skel.so, I am afraid the question might get duplicated as subject will be same [missing file]. so I will just edit the question. Thanks

Comment: @kzs. When I added the dummy array in the mentioned file, I am able to pass that build issue and am stuck with this: now: `make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'adspmsgd.a', needed by 'android_Release/graph_app'.  Stop`. Did you have the same issue?